# data.table and .SDcols with paste0 to create a character vector

Tags: r, data.table

Given the data.table, `DF` below, I would like to select all except the first rows of the groups numbered `6` and `8`. I was told that I should use `paste0( )`. I have a solution that gives the expected result but without `paste0( )`.

```
DF <- data.table(grp=c(6,6,8,8,8), Q1=c(2,2,3,5,2), Q2=c(5,5,4,4,1), Q3=c(2,1,4,2,4), H1=c(3,4,5,2,4), H2=c(5,2,4,1,2) )
```

Desired result:

```
desired_result <- data.table(grp=c(6,8,8), Q1=c(2,4,2), Q2=c(5,4,1), Q3=c(1,2,4) )
```

One method that achieves this result:

```
DF[ , .SD[-1], .SDcols = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), by = grp]
```

How can I use `paste0( )` rather than `c( )`? Is there any advantage to one of these or an example where only one would work?

Comment: You can also do `Q1:Q3`, i.e., `DF[ , .SD[-1], .SDcols = Q1:Q3, by = grp]` (while working interactively) from the next version.. it'll select all the columns in between `Q1` and `Q3` including those cols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method seems to work:

```
DF[ , .SD, .SDcols = paste0("Q", 1:3), by = grp]

   grp Q1 Q2 Q3
1:   6  2  5  2
2:   6  2  5  1
3:   8  3  4  4
4:   8  5  4  2
5:   8  2  1  4
```

Comparing one method to another.

```
all.equal(DF[ , .SD, .SDcols = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), by = grp],
          DF[ , .SD, .SDcols = paste0("Q", 1:3), by = grp])
[1] TRUE
```

Note that `.SDcols` selects columns and has nothing to do with dropping the first rows of each group. `.SDcols` can take a character vector, and `paste0` produces character vectors, so selecting the columns can work either way.

---

One method to drop the first row of each group is `tail` that frivolously includes the `paste0` function is:

```
DF[ , tail(.SD, -1), .SDcols = paste0("Q", 1:3), by = grp]
   grp Q1 Q2 Q3
1:   6  2  5  1
2:   8  5  4  2
3:   8  2  1  4
```